# Email to Salesforce not working with subdomain emails

Tags: email, emailtosalesforce

I faced a problem with 'Email to Salesforce' functionality - emails sent from email addresses with subdomain don't become associated with records.

I added several emails into "My Acceptable Email Addresses", for all the emails everything works well and Salesforce receives them well except email with subdomain (format test@subdomain.domain.com).
For those with the format test@domain.com everything works as expected.

No domains were added to "Excluded Domains".
I also checked the "Unresolved Items" configs - nothing there.
Email messages that should be added to Salesforce are identical as for subdomain email and non-subdomain email
And, just in case, it's under the System Administrator user, all permissions are granted.

I didn't find any topics related to issues with subdomains, would be very grateful for any recommendations!